# How to exit from try block and show exception message?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

This Python code block generates an error at `student [3]`. How to immediately show the error message in `except` rather than printing the previous values?

```
try:

    student = ['bob','rob','mob']
    print (student )
    print (student [0])
    print (student [1])
    print (student [2])
    print (student [3])

except:
    print("error")
```

Current Output:

```
['bob','rob','mob']
bob
rob
mob
error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How could I avoid the printing before the error is raised?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: @TimCastelijns kk ..using that ide :)

Comment: What is the actual message you like to show?

Comment: @thefourtheye ,new in python ,actually i need to jump from try as soon as error is there in try as we do in .net ..and show message in catch or except section

Comment: @utility That is what exactly Python does. It prints `mob` because it can execute as far as `student [2]` is encountered.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Normally, the version of Python also plays a role in the question. So I believe it is better to leave it, unless OP claims otherwise.

Comment: @thefourtheye tag wiki says "If you believe your question includes issues specific to the incompatible Python 2.x or Python 3.x, then in addition to the main tag use python-2.x or python-3.x.". This does not look like a version specific issue to me

Comment: @TimCastelijns but have not tried other versions then how do i know its a version specific error ?

Comment: Your question is in line of "how can I do this", not "I have this issue in pythonX but not in pythonY"

Comment: @TimCastelijns Honestly, I did not understand the question itself till OP explained better in comments. So I agree that version is not relevant to this particular question. Generally I wouldn't remove version tags unless I am absolutely sure.

Comment: point clear @TimCastelijns :)  ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will run until some error happens and the error won't happen until     `print (student [3])`. Therefore previous commands will run and there is now way back.
A simple solution is that you first assign these values to some variables and then print them:

```
try:

    student = ['bob','rob','mob']
    a=student [0]
    b=student [1]
    c=student [2]
    d=student [3]
    print (a)
    print (b)
    print (c)
    print (d)

except:
    print("error")
```

So the error happens in `d=student [3]` before the print commands are executed.

Comment: It works on the basic concept that the code is run line by line.

Comment: thank you @Ali but correct me if im wrong in my code too im printing line by line know .. how come line by line assignment make it different ?

Comment: It is the same thing. But in your code you **print** first. Hereyou **assign** first. Meaning here it will throw the exception at d=student[3], before any printing happens

Comment: You printed those values directly. your code printed three values successfully and when running print(student [3]) it raised an exception and printed the error message.

Comment: Sure thing. Good job on the answer @AliFatolahzadeh ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that AFAIK.

Python doesn't *know* that it is going to encounter an `IndexOutOfBounds` (`IndexError`) exception, so it will execute until getting to the exception.

A way to remedy the situation would be to use a `for` loop and only iterate on that. It should avoid the exception altogether:

```
try:
    student = ['bob','rob','mob']
    for stud in student:
        print stud

except:
    print("error") # less likely to be reached :)
```

Comment: oh..usually in .net i used to see code jumping directly to catch block

Comment: Like I said, it is to my best knowledge. But maybe wait a little longer and someone smarter will have a solution :)

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: (From what I know) - no. There would be no way to skip the printing if you encounter an error. The only better way would be to check you first have the correct number of items *before* iterating.